# "Error querying agent backend. State: URL_TIMEOUT, reason: TIMEOUT_DNSLOOKUP"

Tags: google-smart-home

Since 1.5-2 my google smarthome action was working absolutely fine with device sync, state query and all relevant actions.
Since last 2 months I am getting following error, although I haven't changed anything:

```
0: {
 action: {
 actionType: "STATE_QUERY"
 }
device: {
deviceType: "LIGHT"
}
status: {
externalDebugString: "Error querying agent backend. State: URL_TIMEOUT, reason: TIMEOUT_DNSLOOKUP"
isSuccess: false
statusType: "EXECUTION_BACKEND_FAILURE"
}
}
]
executionType: "PARTNER_CLOUD"
latencyMsec: "2834"
requestId: "5786688694498341746"
}
]
}
locale: "en-US"
}
```

Now, the smart home devices does not report states and control anything and on the Google Home app shows "Not Responding". And strange thing is, sometime it does work (2 out of 10 times I would say).

Another Info:  I have the server hosted at my data centre and absolutely no changes have been made in terms of network, DNS etc.
Can anyone please advise what could be the reason for this? and how it could be resolved. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error returned has the status type EXECUTION_BACKEND_FAILURE which means the Google smart home execution service tried to locate and reach out to your fulfillment endpoint but could not receive a valid response, potentially due to one of many different reasons.

The error log indicates that Google is trying to do a DNS lookup but is failing by timing out. You should check your server settings, and make sure that the domain name & IP matching is happening correctly with your DNS records (you can use a tool like nslookup to verify how it resolves).